# The ancient form of apology 죄송합니다 고어

Tags: word-choice

I often heard a word to apologize in ancient style drama series. Its pronunciation is similar to 송과하옵니다. However the dictionary tells me that 송과 is 松果 which is a fruit.

1. What is the correct spelling of the word I am looking for?
2. Is it still used in modern time?

Comment: Thanks for this. I had been watching some Korean period dramas and had the exact same question. Krim, I'm happy you asked the question and Jick's answerful was helpful! Thanks!!

Answer (score 7):

Correct one is [`송구`](http://m.krdic.naver.com/entry/22258600) . It is still used today, mostly in more formal situations. Note it is more often combined with `-스럽다`, as in `송구스럽습니다` (vs. 미안합니다) or `송구스럽게도 일이 XX하게 되었습니다` (vs. 미안하게도 ...).

Comment: So in the past people use 송구하다, but now 송구스럽다, right?

Comment: 송구하다 is still used, but as an adjective (meaning "to feel sorry"), just not as a stand-alone expression of apology.  E.g., 송구한 마음을 금할 길이 없습니다 would be a fancy way of saying "There is no way I can keep my mind from feeling sorry."  Google "송구한 마음" if you want more examples.

Comment: As for ancient style drama (사극), please keep in mind that they don't actually use *Old Korean*: they merely use a highly stylized version of modern Korean that *sounds* ancient.  If they actually used the authentic Old Korean spoken in the era depicted in the drama, no modern viewers would understand them.

Comment: Along with [jick](http://korean.stackexchange.com/users/409/jick)'s excellent answer, I want to add that this *highly stylized Korean that sounds ancient* often involves `하오`-type endings ([하오체](http://krdic.naver.com/detail.nhn?docid=41347000)). Taking this into account, I believe that OP's example - `송과합니다` is, in fact, a mishearing from `송구하옵니다`.